# Want to create two VM with same VHD running at the same time

Tags: powershell

can I create several machines each having an exact copy of an existing vhd and running at the same time . I have a an OS installation ready and I just want to copy the vhd so that other machines will just point to it and I do not have setup the OS again.'

I want to do this using POwershell Script.Is it possible to do???

Answer (score 0):

Np. everywindows needs its own discs. What you can do is:

- Createa a new differential disc from the master disc image you have. This is a lot faster than making a copy.
- Prepare the differential, then start it and SYSPREP from there.
- Then for a new OS instance, make a copy of the differential for the machine.

You still need one disc per instance (NO WAY AROUND THAT), but you can save a lot of space with that. And you still need to setup the OS again unless you want garbage in your network (the multiple machines can not be distinguished - same SSD, same name). Using unattended install helps here.

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of 'Live CDs' most if not all OS's need to write back to their boot drives, this would stop pretty much any system from doing what you're suggesting. You don't mention which hypervisor you're planning on using (this would be very useful) but VMWare's View product line may be more towards what you're looking for perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect a VHD to more than one VM. And, even if you could (VMware f.e. can do that to simulate a shared cluster storage), this would only make sense for data disks: a Windows system just can't share its *system* disk with another one.

If you want to clone an existing VM, that's fine (but remember to run Sysprep); but what you're asking is not possible at all.